# Title for card in power bi

Tags: powerbi, visualization

Hi everyone from all over the world,
I'm using power bi i want display title below number in  card visualization? The title is arabic language . I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer. Can you help me with that?

I'm using the Version 2.109 for
09/2022

Comment: Did you mean to add a screen grab / image?

Comment: No, I used the card chart to display a number, but the title appears above the number, and I want the title to be below the number.

Comment: Not possible to move the title below a visual. However for a Card visual, you can switch off the title, and instead switch on `Category label`, this appears below the value.